# C program memory violation dependant on std::cout (?)

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy

I've written an extension in C++ for Python, and I'm currently debugging it.
The extension takes 3 numpy matrices and produces 2 as a result. To the inner C++ function that does the actualy calculation I pass 3 float C arrays (just flattened and converted from input numpy arrays), and return a C float array of arrays. Everything works as intended but **ONLY** if I print this output array of arrays before returning it.

What the hell is going on in here?

```
float** gradient(float* inputs, float* kernels, float* grads, npy_intp* input_dims, npy_intp* kernels_dims, npy_intp* output_dims){


float* g_inputs = new float[batch*h*w*ch_in];
for (int i = 0; i < batch*h*w*ch_in; i++) g_inputs[i] = 0;
float* g_kernels = new float[size*ch_out];
for (int i = 0; i < size*ch_out; i++) g_kernels[i] = 0;


float* ret[2] = {{g_inputs}, {g_kernels}};
std::cout<<ret<<std::endl; //<---without this it doesn't work
return ret;
}
```

I've omitted irrelevant code for clarity.

Comment: `new float[batch*h*w*ch_in];` What language is this again? Do you mean C++?

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a pointer to an object with automatic lifetime. In other words, your function returns a dangling pointer, which is Undefined Behaviour.

Although aerostatic lizards are an uncommon result of UB, *anything can happen* and the symptom you observe, unlike the lizards,  is common.

Comment: So does the program automatically call `delete` on objects defined with `new` when returning from the function?

Comment: The array `ret` was not created with `new`. (The two pointers placed into the array were, and they are not deleted, so you also have a memory leak.)

Comment: `ret` preserves the proper address. But `ret[0]` and `ret[1]` don't. How should I fix it?

Comment: Don't try to observe UB. Avoid it. Never return a pointer to a local object. Of course, the dangling pointer does not change, but since what it points to is vacuum, the contents can be reused for other purposes.

Comment: So how can I make that local object global?

Comment: Should I just use keyword `static`?

Comment: If it were me, I'd return a std::tuple. Or even a std::pair

Comment: Otherwise, dynamically allocate a float*[2] and return that.

Comment: And don't forget to delete it and the arrays its elements point to.